# Automated CSS Sprite of svg files phpstorm

Tags: php, css, svg, sprite

I am looking into the best way to serve images. I think svg files and sprite is the best method iv found, I wanted to know if there is way to automate this process. I want to be able to put svg files into a folder and receive a sprite output file and css file with the relevant mapping.

```
 /img
  sprite-icon.svg
/svg
  icon-facebook.svg
  icon-twitter.svg
/css
  icons.css
index.html
```

I am using phpstorm for development.

My first instinct was to create a php script and attach a file watcher.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but none of them are baked into Phpstorm out of the box - but it does make it easy to add them in via the task runner system.

So the method I'm using is to use [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) with the [gulp-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite/) plugin and triggering it from Phpstorm's [Gulp task runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-gulp-task-runner.html#d278525e636).